# Does nexus have to be valid for an amount of time before traveling?

Tags: nexus

For instance, with a normal passport, the United States requires it be valid for a specific amount of time before traveling to the desired country.  In this case, I'm trying to travel to Canada, but I'd like to avoid waiting three months before travel. Is Nexus similar in anyway, or once the application process is over am I free to travel right away?

Comment: I have heard before that a passport should have been valid for a time before you can use it, but never with any proof. As far as I know all those cases are misunderstanding. You can use the passport from day 1, you may need some time at the end of its validity, if not for all countries. If you have proof of that 'three months' rule, I would love to see it.

Comment: Hmmm, thank you, I was at least able to determine I was misreading the "Quick Facts" section on this page:
https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages/Canada.html

Answer (score 3):

I think you've got it backward: Some countries require visitors' passports to have X months validity remaining before their expiration dates. Not that the passport must be valid for X months from the time it was issued. But neither the US nor Canada require this of each other's visitors.

In any event the NEXUS card is valid as soon as you receive it, which owing to the unidirectional nature of time will be after its date of issue, and you can use it the same day.